# Running my Intellij IDE on host, I need ZeroMQ in order to communicate with the backend app on guest

Tags: java, linux, windows, intellij-idea, zeromq

So the set-up is as follows:

- Windows 10 host + using Intellij IDE from host
- Guest virtual machine Debian 8 Jessie, with a running Java backend app + AngularJS/PHP front-end client.

There is also ZeroMQ running on the VM. Now, I want to debug the backend app from my IDE (which is on host) but it appears I should also have ZeroMQ installed in order to allow the communication between the two.

I was also told that probably Win and Linux versions of ZeroMQ are not compatible, but I should give it a try by installing on host and then opening ports on VM.

I hardly know how to proceed. So far I have read some ZeroMQ mailing list entries but I found no useful info about my specific needs.

For starters, has anyone succeeded in achieving similar? Host: Win10, guest VM: Debian 8.

Answer (score 1):

> *(cit.:)* "I was also told that probably Win and Linux versions of ZeroMQ are not compatible"
> **The trust of such a man has gone.**

### Inital note:
ZeroMQ is cross-compatible among all ports that implement it well.

Given the contract-defined services play some role in the implementation, there is no sense to claim any incompatibility. Rational projects use this contract-defined service approach right because of the need to protect the parties against any poor implementation and service, being implemented just-enough to meet the contract-specification is not introducing any havoc into the distributed architectures, that rely on implementation-agnostic services / protocols.

---

### Any to any architectures

Once any pair of applications gets empowered by ZeroMQ, the services may integrate whatever signalling- / messaging- flow one can design and implement.

So, your backend app in java may communicate "over" ZeroMQ Scaleable Formal Communication Patterns with any mix of the service counterparties, be those implemented in Go, Erlang, C++, python, php, FORTRAN, MATLAB, all that irrespective of the transport-class selected for any such `{local|remote}-`host.

The choice of available transport-classes is extended for some virtualisation HyperVisors, so besides the classical choice of
 **`{ inproc:\\ | ipc:\\ | tcp:\\ | pgm:\\ | epgm:\\ }`** plus there is one more for VM-s, using the **`vmci:\\`** transport-class, specific to the efficient use of the HyperVisor mediated interconnections, without building any un-necessary ISO-OSI-L3-overheads.

---

### The best next step:

IMHO if you are serious about professional messaging, get the great book and source both the elementary setups knowledge, a bit more complex multi-socket messaging layer designs with soft signaling & also the further thoughts about the great powers of concurrent, heterogeneous, distributed processing to advance your learning curve.

Pieter Hintjens' book "**Code Connected, Volume 1**" ( available in PDF ) is more than a recommended source for your issue.

There **you will get grounds** for your further use of ZeroMQ.

ZeroMQ is a great tool, not just for the messaging layer itself.

**Worth time & efforts.**

[image: multi-socket messaging layer with soft signalling]